# Comparing tm Type in C++

Tags: c++

I have a `vector<tm> times(x);` object of assorted tm structs, each different than the other.  I would like to check every item in the vector and determine which time is the biggest/lowest.

For example, out of the tm items with times as follows:

```
01:00:00
00:01:00
00:00:01
```

The first would be the largest time, and the last, which is closest to 00:00:00 is the smallest.  Is there any special way to go about finding the largest/smallest struct in the vector, or will I need to design a long looping program to compare each tm struct's hours, minutes and seconds respectively from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

The standard template library contains `std::min_element`, `std::max_element` and `std::minmax_element`. The last one was introduced with c++11 (see [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/minmax_element/)) and should help you if `tm` is comparable.

Answer (score 0):

Use mktime(tm) and compare the returned values.  The returned values are in epoch time which means larger values are more recent in time.

Comment: The times I'm using are really just durations, only the hour/minute/second field is populated, which means mktime() cannot make a calendar time, returns -1.

Comment: Then store the times a unsigned long instead of the tm struct.  It can be the number of seconds as the duration, then they are ordered with the < or > comparison.